# "Address not available" error at ng serve with Angular

Tags: angular-cli

I'm trying to compile a simple (first) Angular project on Visual Studio. I'm connected to a Hotspot. When I run `ng serve` I get the following error:

**An unhandled exception occurred: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL: address not available 40.68.249.35:4200
See "/private/var/folders/jc/mgkz9l6x7h52sz7dcp8mrr_m0000gn/T/ng-3legRp/angular-errors.log" for further details.**

```
[error] Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL: address not available 40.68.249.35:4200
at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1296:21)
at listenInCluster (net.js:1361:12)
at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.doListen [as callback] (net.js:1498:7)
at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:68:8)
```

How can I solve this error? Currently I always use the command `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0` which works...

Answer (score 2):

Go to your **angular.json**,
Have you specified a host?

```
"serve": {
      ...
        "development": {
          ...
          "host": "example.com",
        },
```

Make sure **example.com** is included in your /etc/hosts file.

```
$ vi /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost   example.com
```

Comment: This! Someone added a `host` to our angular.json without telling us.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `ng serve --port=7845`

You can use any other port also.

Comment: Tried some different ports, but I still get the same error

Comment: are you still passing this argument  `--host 0.0.0.0` to `ng serve` command

Answer (score 0):

You possibly is using your public IP address, from your internet router or VPN. This occurs when searching for the IP on websites like *WhatIsMyIpAddress*.

So, just **get you private IP correctly** running "`ipconfig`" on prompt command (use IPv4).

> At my usually, using Visual Studio Code, open terminal on the project,
> run "`ipconfig`" and then run "`ng serve ip.got.early.here`".

---

Any of other solutions work for me, like changing port, using ngrok, turning on/off the VPN and any other tips.

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same error when trying to use my external IP. When I tried ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 it worked fine but I was only able to connect with my LAN IP4 address (192.168.1.110) but I was not able to access the application with the external IP.

I fix this by doing Port Forwarding on my router on port 4200 so that it redirects from the external IP to the local IP, after that, I run ng serve --host 0.0.0.0, and I was able to access the application with the external IP.